# How to navigate gdm3 login manager with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, login-screen, gdm

Pretty much I want to know how to access the cog-icon with a keyboard shortcut. Is there a way? (Everything I know about Linux tells me there should be and probably is.)

I know this is a question that reeks of "did you google it?", but yes I have and I've found nothing. My Google-fu is weak or I am just using the wrong terminology when asking the question? I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your account selected, i.e., the cursor on the password field, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Space</kbd> to open the cog menu.